# Accessing index of particular values in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I have a matrix of coordinates (numpy arrays)

```
arr = [[a,b,c],
       [d,e,f],
       ......]]
```

where every tuple is unique, but a,b,c,d,e,f are not.

I'm wondering how to obtain the index at which

```
arr == [d,e,f]
```

I'm using

```
np.where(arr==[d,e,f])
```

but it returns a whole mess of values at which other individual elements are true.

For example,

```
vals = arr==[d,e,f]
```

returns

```
vals = [[False,False,False],
        [True,True,True],
         ...............]]
```

But doing

```
 np.where(vals==[True,True,True])
```

returns the other elements that contain only one or two trues, as well as the three trues. I just want the one tuple with all three trues.

Comment: Is your `arr` a numpy array or just a list of lists?

Comment: Numpy arrays! I added it in the question too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the indices of the rows that has all `True`s by using [`numpy.all`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.all.html#numpy.all) on 1st axis:

```
>>> arr1 = np.array(['d', 'e', 'f'])
>>> arr2 = np.array([['a' , 'b', 'c'],
       ['d', 'e', 'f'],
       ['g', 'h', 'i']])
>>> np.all(arr2==arr1, axis=1)
array([False,  True, False], dtype=bool)
# Now get the indices using `numpy.where`
>>> np.where(np.all(arr2==arr1, axis=1))[0]
array([1])
>>> arr2[_]
array([['d', 'e', 'f']], 
      dtype='|S1')
```